# Flash Media Server and XMPP Server Communication, is it possible?

Tags: apache-flex, xmpp, flash-media-server

i create a chat application using Adobe FLEX, currently it is not implemented yet, but i have a plan to use Flash Media Server as the chat server. The problem is my application should be able to communicate with other XMPP server such as AIM or Google talk. Is it possible to do that? or is there any better solution?

**UPDATE**

The point i needed here is the possibility to communicate with the 3rd party XMPP server (Google Talk, AOL/AIM). I have read that Google Talk, AOL/AIM has open the XMPP server to server communication. Is FMS possible to do that?

Regards
Kin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of XMPP protocol implementation in ActionScript, so it is possible to integrate with an XMPP server - take a look on [XIFF](http://www.igniterealtime.org/) library.

Note: you can also use BlazeDS as a chat server instead of FMS.

Comment: I thought BlazeDS didn't have any push functionality?  I was about to recommend GraniteDS and/or LiveCycle before reading the wikipedia entry on FMS; which states chat rooms as one of the use cases.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Media_Server

Comment: BlazeDS has all the messaging features from LCDS with some exceptions:
a)no RTMP/NIO channels (but being open source one can create a NIO endpoind for using BlazeDS with a NIO based servlet container
b)message throttling and message reliability exists only in LCDS
I would use BlazeDS instead of GraniteDS for messaging because I think it is more mature..but also because I know the first product much better.
Regarding FMS I the main advantage brought by BlazeDS (and LCDS) is the integration with JAVA world. Also BlazeDS is open source and you can take a look in the code when you have problems.

Comment: Thanks guys, The point that i need here is the possibility to communicate with the 3rd party XMPP server. I have read that Google Talk, AOL/AIM has open the XMPP server to server communication. Is there either BlazeDS or GraniteDS possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, by integrating an XMPP java library with one of these two products.